# for loop not making multiple buttons correctly

Tags: javascript, loops, createelement

So i'm trying to make multiple buttons with a for loop such as

```
    const buttonSection = document.getElementById('listOfFiles');
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++){
        const questionnaireSelector = document.createElement('input');
        questionnaireSelector.type = 'button';
        questionnaireSelector.id = 'selectorButton' + i;
        questionnaireSelector.value = arrayOfFiles[i];
        buttonSection.appendChild(questionnaireSelector);
```

and instead of making a button for each element in the arrayOfFiles array which is populated earlier on in the code, it makes one button and instead just writes all of the contents of the array into the value of that one button.

Would anyone be able to help?
Thanks

Comment: you should use var or let instead of const for the input button

Comment: my lecturer would publicly execute me if he saw that i used var in a local context unfortunately

Comment: Include more of your code, especially the part where the array gets populated. Use breakpoints and/or `console.log()`s to check the state of the script at various points/iterations.

Answer (score 0):

I have added the necessary missing elements. You should replace them.

HTML:

```
<div id='listOfFiles'></div>
```

JS:

```
    const buttonSection = document.getElementById('listOfFiles');
    const arrayOfFiles = [1,2,3,4] // to be replaced

    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++){
        const questionnaireSelector = document.createElement('input');
        questionnaireSelector.type = 'button';
        questionnaireSelector.id = 'selectorButton' + i;
        questionnaireSelector.value = arrayOfFiles[i];
        buttonSection.appendChild(questionnaireSelector);
    }
```

[see it in action](https://jsfiddle.net/site2goal/wp3Lbjt4/)

Comment: there was already a html element there, i replaced my code with yours and changed the section to a div and it didn't do anything. It still makes one button and just puts the entire array into that one button. EDIT: It's very weird behaviour now that i saw that your code works properly on JSFiddle

Comment: You did not modify your code correctly. The example does work. Just look more carefuly or share the real code. Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, because the contents of the array are retrieved from the server in array form already, when i push it to arrayOfFiles it becomes a nested array. Which is why it only makes one button as it takes the index[0] of the encapsulating array. Full code :

```
"use strict";

const arrayOfFiles = [];


async function getListFromServer(){
    const response = await fetch('/api/viewQuestionnaires');
    const directory = await response.json();

    arrayOfFiles.push(directory);
}

function displayListOfFiles(){
    revealButton.remove();
    const buttonSection = document.getElementById('listOfFiles');
    for (let i = 0; i < arrayOfFiles.length; i++){
        let questionnaireSelector = document.createElement('input');
        questionnaireSelector.type = 'button';
        questionnaireSelector.id = 'selectorButton' + i;
        questionnaireSelector.value = arrayOfFiles[i];
        buttonSection.appendChild(questionnaireSelector);
    }
}
```

Comment: fixed it by adding arrayOfFiles[0].length in the for loop limit and questionnaireSelector.value = arrayOfFiles[0][i] when assigning values which accessed the nested array